# Use a twig variable inside a twig render

Tags: theming, entities

I am rendering a node field (which is an url to an image) in the node template file like bellow

```
<section class="bg" style="background-image: url({{ file_url(node.field_picture_bg.entity.fileuri) }});">
```

Works as its supposed to, but i have some logic which tests which exact image field to render and i would like to render the field name from a variable, like so bellow (WHICH DOESNT WORK obviously :) ).

```
<section class="bg" style="background-image: url({{ file_url(node.MYVARIBLE.entity.fileuri) }});">
```

Where `MYVARIBLE` is the name of the field. Is this even possible in twig?
I know i can archive this with an conditional clause since there are only 2 possibilities for the field name, but this way is more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the variable inside of the method [get()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21ContentEntityBase.php/function/ContentEntityBase%3A%3Aget/8.4.x):

```
{{ node.get(MYVARIBLE).entity.fileuri }}
```

Comment: Yup, that's it. Thanks a bunch. I searched the Twig docs and couldn't find this anywhere.

Comment: You can use all object methods whitelisted in TwigSandboxPolicy. These are for example all named or prefixed `get`, but not `set`.